# create view for each category - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I currently print all categories in one view, with them I mark a difference between its subcategories

```html
@foreach($tipos as $tipo)
   <div class="card">
     
  <h4 style="margin-top: 5px;">{{$tipo->tipo }}</h4> 
  </div> 
    @foreach($tipo->categories as $category)
  <div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="{{ route('category-detail',['slug'=>$category->slug]) }}">
        @if(!empty($category->image))
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($category->image)}}" alt="">
        @else
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
        @endif
      </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a href="{{ route('category-detail',['slug'=>$category->slug]) }}">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{$category->descripcion}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

[image: categories]

I get the names from:

[image]

categories table:
[image]
**Now I need to create a view for each of them, enter it using url**,

controller:

```
public function list($id){

   $tipos = App\Tipo::findOrFail($id);
   return view('list.tipos', compact('tipos'));
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('/list{id}','HomeController@list')->name('list.categories');
```

pivot table:

[image]

**How can I print the content of each category?** help pls

Comment: you want list of categories or tipos ? and provide your categories table here as well which would help alot. :)

Comment: I want to create views with types, inside types print the categories

Comment: the categories table :) edited

Comment: Okay bro let me see

Comment: And one type have only one category ?\

Comment: I want to insert more than one category,  it is an example

Comment: I have added an answer, check it once and let me know if it is helpful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your controller like this 
**Note:** Change the Model Names `(App\Pivote)` and  `(App\Category)` to what you have set in your code.

```
public function list($id){

   $tipos = App\Tipo::findOrFail($id);
   $pivot_data = App\Pivote::select('category_id')->where('tipo_id',$id)->get()->toArray();
   $categories = App\Category::whereIn('id',$pivot_data)->get()->toArray();
   return view('list.tipos', compact('tipos','categories'));
}
```

And modify your view something like this

```
<div class="card">     
    <h4 style="margin-top: 5px;">{{$tipos->tipo }}</h4> 
</div> 
@foreach($categories as $key => $category)
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <a href="{{ route('category-detail',['slug'=>$category['slug']]) }}">
            @if(!empty($category['image']))
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset($category['image'])}}" alt="">
            @else
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            @endif
            </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
                <a href="{{ route('category-detail',['slug'=>$category['slug']]) }}">{{$category['name']}}</a>
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{$category['descripcion']}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: it works, but the category image doesn't show it, run the if and don't throw error.  $image = Category::all();
        return view('store.list', compact('tipos','image','categories')); I included this variable but the image continues without seeing

Comment: @user13523236 I've changed the answer above for image, check it once

Comment: I think you cannot find the image from the db

Comment: @user13523236 No actually you have to wrap up the image path into asset() to get the url which is needed by an Image Tag

Comment: @user13523236 can you check the above answer once ?

Comment: okay i did but still can't find it. when I do another foreach if it shows the image but it shows the one of all types https://pastebin.com/sWGNUtH1

Comment: @user13523236 can you show me your full code of view ?